# One form for multiple addresses in Symfony - Twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, for-loop, twig

**First I want to make clear that I'm not using Entities/Doctrine for my forms (or even). I'm using webservices to add/edit the data fields for the database**

I'm working on a project where I need to edit company information with multiple addresses.
The first address is always the physical address so I grab that in the same loop as the company data.

However the second (and third, or fourth if exist) address is placed in a seperate database entry. 
I'm able to edit the company data and the company address (physical address) with a single form (because the data is all in one set) Thus I only need one form for this, and don't have to use a loop for the address.

---

Now I want to edit the second address. I'm looping through the addresses in twig and print out all the other addresses for that company.
As I'm aware Symfony doesn't allow multiple instances of the same form, because this wil interfere with ID's etc.

The question is how I'm supposed to render the form only for a specific address. which I want to edit with the click of a button (using bootstrap collapse to hide the form if not editing)

My code looks like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function editcompany(Request $request, $klantnr)
{

    [...]

    $result = [
        'gegevens' => [],
        'addresses' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($company as $row) {
        $dataFields = [
            [...] // The data fields of the company (including the physical address)
        ];
        foreach ($dataFields as $dataField) {
            if (empty($result['gegevens'][$dataField])) {
                $result['gegevens'][$dataField] = $row[$dataField];
            }
        }
        if($row['AdrGid'] != $result['gegevens']['AdrGid']) {
            $result['addresses'][$row['AdrGid']] = [
                [...] // The data fields for the other addresses 
            ];
        }
    }

    // The form creation of the company data form
    $form = $this->createForm(EditcompanyForm::class);

    // The form of the other addresses
    $form_adres = $this->createForm(EditcompanyAdresForm::class, array(
        [...]
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form_adres->handleRequest($request);


    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        [...] // Handling the submitted data for the company data
    }

    // GEKOPPELDE ADRESSEN company
    if($form_adres->isSubmitted() && $form_adres->isValid()) {

        [...]

        $data = array(
            [...] // Setting the data for the other addresses
        );

        [...]

        // Passing the data and other options to the webservices
        $this->get('http')->companyRequest($data, $admincode, $service, $token);

        $request->getSession()
            ->getFlashBag()
            ->add('success', 'Linked address successfully edited');

        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
    }

    return $this->render('pages/company/edit.html.twig', array(
        'client' => $result,
        'form_company' => $form->createView(),
        'form_company_adres' => $form_adres->createView()
    ));
 }
```

**Formbuilder (AbstractType):**

```
class EditcompanyAdresForm extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $factuuradres = $options['NawFactuurAdres'];
        $lands = $options['lands'];

        $data = array();
        $builder
            [...] // Add the necessary fields
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            [...] // setting defaults here
        ));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_form_editcompanyadresform';
    }
}
```

**Twig template (showing addresses:**

```
{% for address in client.addresses %}
    <div class="right-cont-grey">
        [...] // showing addresses
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Twig template (editing form):**

```
{% for address in client.addresses %}
    {{ form_start(form_company_adres, {'  method': 'POST'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form_company_adres._token) }}
        <section class="collapse" id="adres_plus">
            <div id="adres" class="new-adres collapse right-cont-grey">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    [...] // Form_widgets with values from database
            </div>
        </section>
    {{ form_end(form_company_adres) }}
{% endfor %}
```

**So in short:**

How can I use the address form for every address without it interferring? Maybe create the view (render) within the twig file inside the loop?
**My form is pre-filled with data from the database, so that I can edit that.**

Comment: This sounds a lot like you could use the [collection field type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). Have you tried that?

Comment: @Yoshi I haven't tried that yet, but that looks great. I think I haven't read about it yet because there's not much about it on the web a part from the docs. Also, is it possible to use this if you're not using Entities?

Comment: Forms in general do not require any orm entities. Though using real model classes helps a lot, those models need not necessarily be the actual models (entities) that get saved to the database. I often use [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to simplify form handling in special cases.

Comment: In my opinion I'm using a good alternative to entities. I created my own models, I call them repositories, but they're basically models, I just do the queries there and pass it to the controller. If you need the code for that I can add that aswell

Comment: No need to :) I really just wanted to give you some references regarding the collection type. For now, to me, it seems a perfect fit for your requirements.

Comment: @Yoshi Do you mind sharing an example for my case? It still looks a bit complex and I don't really know how to get started with it.

Comment: Short question, those extra address, should the form allow to add/remove any of them?

Comment: @Yoshi For adding I'm planning on adding a seperate form action. There won't be a function to delete an address (yet), but this could be added in the future. It should be, but the webservices are not allowing me right now.

Comment: I added my answer, note it's very simple for now. If you have any questions just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*revised answer with regards to what we talked about in chat:*

As I wrote in the comment, I'm sure you only need to setup a [collection field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). The whole complexity then basically *goes away*.

A very simple example would be:

**controller**:

```
public function editCompanyAction(Request $request)
{
    // get the data anyway you see fit and produce a model (this could also be a dedicated DTO)
    $company = $this->getInput();

    // create the form
    $form = $this
        ->createForm(CompanyWithAddressesType::class, $company)
        ->handleRequest($request)
    ;

    // handle submission
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        dump($form->getData()); // === $company
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

**the forms**

The important part here is that the names of the fields you add match the keys in the array which is supplied as data!

```
class CompanyWithAddressesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // combine the company with a collection of addresses:
        $builder
            ->add('gegevens', CompanyType::class)
            ->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }
}

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // all the fields that are *extra* for companies, address fields are inherited
        // because this type extends the address type (see below getParent)
        $builder
            ->add('NawWebsite', TextType::class)
            ->add('email1', TextType::class)
            ->add('AdrNaam1', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @return @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return AddressType::class;
    }
}

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // all the fields that define an address
        $builder
            ->add('AdrStraat', TextType::class)
            ->add('AdrHuisnummer', TextType::class)
            ->add('AdrPostcode', TextType::class)
            ->add('NawFactuurAdres', CheckboxType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

**twig**:

Simply output the form. Any [form customization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) is applicable

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div>
        <h4>Company</h4>
        {{ form_row(form.gegevens.NawWebsite) }}
        {{ form_row(form.gegevens.email1) }}
        {{ form_row(form.gegevens.AdrNaam1) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        <h4>Main address</h4>
        {{ form_rest(form.gegevens) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        <h4>Extra addresses</h4>
        {% for address in form.addresses %}
            {{ form_errors(address) }}
            {{ form_widget(address) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: It's hard for me to translate these models to my own code, because I'm not using the symfony model structure at all in my project. What I have is a controller that gets the form (from my abstracttype formbuilder), a model class (simply a file that queries the data from db and returns to controller) and an abstracttype class where I build my forms. I populate the fields in the twig template (this part should be done in the controller as you did)

Comment: I understand, but I don't see the problem. As I wrote, at some point in the controller, regardless of how it came to be, you should have a single value that represents the company with it's addresses. This value then will be the one manipulated by the form. For example, use some intermediary model (DTO) which you create on the fly using the actual data. Then pass that DTO to the form. On submission use the data in the model to update the actual data (e.g. using your custom logic). This really has nothing to do with the symfony model structure, you only need a controller and a form.

Comment: What I want to say is: If your actual model is too complicated or too much of a hassle to translate to something that can be used with symfony forms, just create an intermediary, and map data in and out.

Comment: The thing is, I've started working with symfony little over a month ago, and was forced to use odbc, so I skipped the whole model part of symfony because I couldn't use that (There's nothing on the web about symfony models without an orm) so maybe I'll understand it if I try it, but for now it's a bit vague

Comment: But to be clear, the stuff you do with $foo, $bar, $baz, etc is basically an alternative to what I do with 
`$result['addresses'][$row['AdrGid']] = [ [...] ];` e.g. Getting the data to put in the form fields (however this is done in twig, and not in the controller). I should read up on data transformers

Comment: I fell into that same trap when I first started using symfony. All the docs used model/entity and everywhere it seems to be a doctrine *thing*. So let me make this clear, pretty much nowhere you're required to use doctrine. Often, when there is talk about a *model*, it only refers to some data container you can give a name. Often a php class is the easiest thing to use, but that class does not need to be doctrine entity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161437/discussion-between-yoshi-and-kees-sonnema).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to place the form outside of the loop and then have a hidden input field that identifies the address which needs to be saved on submit. So when the other fields are not displayed, they are not submitted.
That means you need some Javascript logic to display and hide the addresses.

**Twig template (editing form):**

```
{{ form_start(form_company_adres, {'  method': 'POST'}) }}
{% for address in client.addresses %}
    <div id="address-{{ loop.index }}" class="address">
        <input type="hidden" name="address-number" value="{{ loop.index }}"/>
        {{ form_row(form_company_adres._token) }}
            <section class="collapse" id="adres_plus">
                <div id="adres" class="new-adres collapse right-cont-grey">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        [...] // Form_widgets with values from database
                </div>
            </section>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form_company_adres) }}
```

Comment: Okay so I have a question. Using this code there is no way to determine the id of an address, so I can't give back the correct data. Should I add a second hidden field for that?

Comment: FYI it is always printing address-1`. I'm probably missing something, but I couldn't figure this out before.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, just replace the loop.index with the ID of the address. Then you should determine which address was saved. If these are auto incremented IDs from a database be sure to check if the user is allowed to change the address, so not to run into trouble that users can change different users addresses.

Btw loop.index shouldn't be always 1, check here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable